# Get automatically coordinates of subplots in order to set them for automatic positioning of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, legend

I tried in a first time to set manually the location for the main legend of a main plot produced by [Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

The plot below represents the 1/2 sigma confidence levels coming from a covariance matrix with joint distributions. It is produced by [Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

[image: Legend manually positioned]

The main routine that generates this plot is :

```
    # g.settings
    g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()
    g.settings.figure_legend_frame = True
    g.settings.legend_fontsize = 21
        g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                          names,
                          filled = True,
                          contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                          line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                          {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}]
                          )

g.add_legend(['Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into accound a = 200',\
  'Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into account a = 300' ],\
  bbox_to_anchor = [1.5, 8.5])
```

The value `1.5` seems to correspond to the x-coordinate (width) `8.5` corresponds to the y-coordinate of legend (height).

Now, I would like to automatically do this process instead of set manual at each time the position of the legend.

I want the top right of the legend to be positioned at the top border of the first left upper box (just at the level of top line border below the "1sigma ± 0.0012" title).

I would like also the legend to be pushed to the right of the figure (up to the right border for the right lower box of the figure: identified by `sigma8` `"1sigma ± 0.001" title` ; Caution: I want it located before the 1.0 and 0.0 xticks, just at the x-coordinate of right line border).

Here what I tried to get the global coordinates (the entire plot) of the top border for this left upper box :

```
# First, get y coordinates of top border for first Likelihood
  box1 = g.subplots[0,0]
  box1_coords = box1._position.bounds
  print('box1_coords = ', box1_coords)
```

and I get at the execution the following values :

```
box1_coords =  (0.125, 0.7860975609756098, 0.09451219512195125, 0.09390243902439022)
```

As you can see, these values seem to be normalized, **so I don't know how to handle if I want to insert these values into :**

```
bbox_to_anchor = [box1_coords[0], box1_coords[1]]
```

This line of code produces a bad position for legend, as expected.

So, how can I manage to automatically assign the good values for bbox_to_anchor to get what I want (y-coordinate at level of top border of left upper box identified by the `"1sigma ± 0.0012" title`) and pushed on the right side up to the right border of right lower box (x-coordinate identified by sigma8 with `"1sigma ± 0.001" title`)?

### Update 1

I tried to adapt them to my case, but issue still occurs. Here what I have done:

```
# g.settings
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()

# get the max y position of the top left axis
top_left_plot = g.subplots[0,0].axes.get_position().ymax
# get the max x position of the bottom right axis
# it is -1 to reference the last plot
bottom_right_plot = g.subplots[-1,-1].axes.get_position().xmax
```

I don't know why the values of `top_left_plot` and `bottom_right_plot` are not the good ones.

I think that `subplots[0,0]` (for top `y-coordinate` of legend) refers to the top left subplot and `subplots[-1,-1]` to the bottom right subplot (for right `x-coordinate` of legend) but considering this, it doesn't work.

For example :

```
# g.settings
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()
# Call triplot
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                names,
                filled = True,
                legend_labels = [],
                contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}])

g.add_legend(['Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into accound a = 200',
'Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into account a = 300'],
legend_loc='upper right',
bbox_to_anchor=(bottom_right_plot, top_left_plot)
)
```

I get :

```
legend_coords y_max, x_max  0.88 0.9000000000000001
```

I can't understand why these values (seems to be comprised between 0.0 and 1.0) are not taken into account with `g.add_legend`.

With `@mullinscr`'s solution, I get the following figure :

[image: wrong legend position]

If I take for the coordinates of legend position by forcing :

```
top_left_plot = 8.3
bottom_right_plot = 1.0
```

This looks like to the first figure of this post. But these 2 values are not comprised between 0.0 and 1.0 like it should.

### Update 2

`@mullinscr`, thanks, I have followed your update and always get an issue. If I apply the same code snippet directly in my script, i.e :

```
g.add_legend(['An example legend - item 1'],
         legend_loc='upper right', # we want to specify the location of this point
         bbox_to_anchor=(bottom_right_plot, top_left_plot),
         bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, # this is the x and y co-ords we extracted above
         borderaxespad=0, # this means there is no padding around the legend
         edgecolor='black')
```

Then I get the following figure :

[image: solution suggested]

As you can see, the coordinates are not really what is really expected : a slight shift on `x-coordinate` and `y-coordinate` is present.

If I apply your code snippet for my legend text, I get:

[image: method applied to my case]

I give you the link of my entire script, this will be easier maybe for you to see an error compared what is expected:

[My entire Python script](http://31.207.36.11/triplot_for_SO.py)

Comment: Have you tried `fig.legend()` ?

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal** working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), building this helps yourself in narrowing down the possible errors and it makes it way easier for others to help you.
The code you provided does not run as you load data from disk...
By checking your file I noticed that you use the keyword `bbox_inches='tight'`, did you try to leave this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer, it's the same as @scleronomic's answer, but I'll point out some of the things that tripped me up when figuring this out.

Below is my code to reproduce your desired positioning, I've tried to create the same subplot layout to you, but through matplotlib not getdist -- same result though.

As you discovered, the trick lies in extracting the position data of the first and last axes (top-left and lower-right), to reference from. The bounds method that you used returns: the x0, y0, width and height of the axes (see the docs). However what we want is the *maximum* x and y, so that our legend corner is in the top right. This can be achieved by using the xmax and ymax method:

```
axes.flatten()[-1].get_position().xmax
axes.flatten()[0].get_position().ymax
```

Once we have these variables they can be passed into the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter of the `add_legend()` function, as you did. However, if we use `loc='upper right'` too, it tells matplotlib that we want the upper right of the legend to be pinned to this top right corner. Finally, we need to set `borderaxespad=0` otherwise the legend won't sit exactly where we want it to due to default padding.

Please see my example code below, as well as the resulting picture. Note that I left the top-right plot in so you can see that it lines up correctly.

Also, note that as @scleronomic says, calls to `plt.tight_layout()` etc will mess this positioning up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# code to layout subplots as in your example:
# --------------------------------------------
g, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=7, ncols=7,figsize=(10,10))

unwanted = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,17,
            18,19,20,25,26,27,33,34,41]

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.plot([1,2], [1,2])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])

for n, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):    
    if n in unwanted:
        ax.remove()
        
# Code to answer your question:
# ------------------------------

# get the max y position of the top left axis
top_left_plot = axes.flatten()[0].get_position().ymax
# get the max x position of the bottom right axis
# it is -1 to reference the last plot
bottom_right_plot = axes.flatten()[-1].get_position().xmax

# I'm using the matplotlib so it is g.legend() not g.add_legend
# but g.add_legend() should work the same as it is a wrapper of th ematplotlib func
g.legend(['Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into accound a = 200',
  'Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taking into account a = 300'],
         loc='upper right', # we want to specify the location of this point
         bbox_to_anchor=(bottom_right_plot, top_left_plot), # this is the x and y co-ords we extracted above
         borderaxespad=0, # this means there is no padding around the legend
         edgecolor='black') # I set it black for this example

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update**

After @youpilat13's comments, I investigated some more and installed getdist to try and recreate with that tool. Initially I got the same results, but found the trick is, unlike if you were making this in matplotlib, you have to transform the legend's coordinates to figure coordinates. This can be achieved with the following in the `g.add_legend()` call:

```
bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import getdist
from getdist import plots, MCSamples
from getdist.gaussian_mixtures import GaussianND
covariance = [[0.001**2, 0.0006*0.05, 0], [0.0006*0.05, 0.05**2, 0.2**2], [0, 0.2**2, 2**2]]
mean = [0.02, 1, -2] 
gauss=GaussianND(mean, covariance)
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter(subplot_size=3)
g.triangle_plot(gauss,filled=True)

top_left_plot = g.subplots.flatten()[0].get_position().ymax
bottom_right_plot = g.subplots.flatten()[-1].get_position().xmax

g.add_legend(['An example legend - item 1'],
         legend_loc='upper right', # we want to specify the location of this point
         bbox_to_anchor=(bottom_right_plot, top_left_plot),
         bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, # this is the x and y co-ords we extracted above
         borderaxespad=0, # this means there is no padding around the legend
         edgecolor='black')
```

And the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know bbox also has `xmax`, `ymax` attribute, that is easier

Comment: @mulilinscr . Thank for your answer. I have some problems to reproduce the same behavior with GetDist library. You can see my **UPDATE 1** where I give more details of what I have tried. If you could take a look at this, I would be grateful. Regards

Comment: @mullinscr. Thanks for your quick answer. I have applied your solution directly into my script instead of my version of `g.add_legend` : you can see there are yet shifts on `x-coordinates`  and `y-coordinates`. If I adapt your snippet code into my script, the problem remains. So, I give you the following link of my entire script : `http://31.207.36.11/triplot_for_SO.py` . I don't want to be boring but maybe this will be easier for you to see what's wrong. I suspect   `Constrained Layout` or `using bbox_inches='tight'` to put the mess but I am not sure.

Comment: Without the data to run the code exactly I can't really see what is going on. I would suggest commenting out `g.settings.constrained_layout = True` (or set it to False) and then also try commenting out `g.fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.1, right = 0.98, top = 0.95, bottom = 0.1, hspace = 0.25, wspace = 0.25)`. Try toggling these and running the code and see where it gets you. The `g.fig.savefig()` call won't be affecting it.

Comment: @mullinscr . Thanks a lot, that did it by using `g.settings.constrained_layout = False` and put `g.fig.subplots_adjust` just after `g.add_legend` (I think since otherwise, I do some computations on `x_tick` that potentially implies no wanted shifts for legend. Now I am faced to another issue without links with here, this will be another post. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It basically works as you described. The bboxes `(xmin, ymin, width, height)` of the axes are given in fractions of the figure and `plt.legend()` uses the same format so the two are compatible. By setting the `upper right` corner of the legend to the corner defined by the outer most axes you get the clean layout and don't have to worry about the exact size of the legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 4

# Create the subplot grid
# Alternative: fig, ax = plt.subplots(n, n); ax[i, j].remove() for j > i
fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=n, ncols=n)
ax = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=object)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j <= i:
            ax[i, j] = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, j])
# add this to make the position of the legend easier to spot
ax[0, -1] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, -1])

# Plot some dummy data 
ax[0, 0].plot(range(10), 'b-o', label='Dummy Label 4x4')

# Set the legend
y_max = ax[0][0].get_position().ymax
x_max = ax[-1][-1].get_position().xmax
fig.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(x_max, y_max),
           borderaxespad=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Some pitfalls could be using the [`Constrained Layout`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html)
or using `bbox_inches='tight'` when saving the file as both screw up the position of the legend in unexpected ways.

For some more examples of legend placement I found [this collection](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/01/23/matplotlib-legend-outside-of-axes/) 
very helpful.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Unfortunately, I have difficulties to reproduce the same behavior with GetDist library. You can see my **UPDATE 1** where I give details of what I have done. If you could take a look, this would be fine. Regards